# How to reference a column by its index and see if any of them have a certain value r

Tags: r, indexing, dplyr

I have the following dataframe, and this is just a sample. I have 530 columns but I know the index of the columns that I need to check whether they contain certain values. I want to check whether column a, b, c, d contain the value 1. If they do then "YES", if not, then "NO". I ONLY want to reference the columns by their position not name.

```
df=data.frame(row_number=c(1,2,3,4),a=c(1,0,0,0),b=c(1,1,1,0),c=c(1,1,0,0),d=c(1,1,0,0))
```

I have tried this but it's not working, any suggestions?

```
df%>%mutate(check=ifelse(any(colnames(df[,c(2:5)])==1), "YES","NO"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that:

- columns a, b, c and d contain **only** 1 or 0
- you want to check if **any** column contains 1

then one approach is to check that the row sum over those columns is > 0.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(check = ifelse(rowSums(.[, 2:5]) > 0, "YES", "NO"))
```

Result:

```
  row_number a b c d check
1          1 1 1 1 1   YES
2          2 0 1 1 1   YES
3          3 0 1 0 0   YES
4          4 0 0 0 0    NO
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pmax` to get maximum in each row and change 1 to `'Yes'` and 0 to `'No'`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(check = ifelse(do.call(pmax, select(.,2:5)), 'Yes','No'))

#  row_number a b c d check
#1          1 1 1 1 1   Yes
#2          2 0 1 1 1   Yes
#3          3 0 1 0 0   Yes
#4          4 0 0 0 0    No
```